# Flask SQL Alchemy vs MyPy - error with Model type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, mypy

I came across the following problem with the combination of `flask_sqlalchemy` and `mypy`. When I define a new ORM object like:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    pass
```

where `db` is a database created using **SQL Alchemy** applied to `flask` app, `mypy` type check produces the following error:

> error: Class cannot subclass 'Model' (has type 'Any')

I would like to mention that I have `sqlalchemy-stubs` installed. Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: Unfortunately, `sqlalchemy-stubs` contains type hints for just the sqlalchemy library, but not flask_sqlalchemy. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs/issues/76) asking for support for flask_sqlalchemy, but it doesn't look like anybody's started work on it yet. Perhaps you could try making your own basic stubs, taking inspiration from the existing ones? Somebody in the issue also mentioned they were able to use models from sqlalchemy directly and hook them into Flask, which let them be properly typed. Perhaps you could investigate that approach?

Answer (score 5):

Until [stubs for `flask_sqlalchemy`](https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs/issues/76) are officially supported, you can instead use `sqlalchemy.orm.DeclarativeMeta` to 'alias' to `db.Model` as pointed out [in this response](https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs/issues/76#issuecomment-595839159):

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta

BaseModel: DeclarativeMeta = db.Model


class Foo(BaseModel):
    pass
```

Comment: `DeclarativeMeta` seems to have moved to `sqlalchemy.orm` in later versions of `flask-sqlalchemy`, thus the import becomes `from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeMeta`

Answer (score -4):

Untill the issue is close you can set more [loyal](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#suppressing-errors) configuration MyPy for your project through mypy.ini

```
[mypy]
ignore_errors = True
```

This will ignore all non-fatal errors