# Flask SQL Alchemy and MyPy error with db.model - Incompatible types in assignment

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, mypy

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[Any]", variable has type "DefaultMeta")  [assignment]
error: Variable "application.models.BaseModel" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
```

Previously it worked when it was declared like this

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta
BaseModel: DeclarativeMeta = db.Model
```

But after packages update I'm seeing that error again. I've read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774322/flask-sql-alchemy-vs-mypy-error-with-model-type) that DeclarativeMeta was moved to `sqlalchemy.orm`, but when tried

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeMeta
BaseModel: DeclarativeMeta = db.Model
```

I can still see the error. I've also noticed that sometimes `flask_sqlalchemy` is used

```
from flask_sqlalchemy.model import DefaultMeta
BaseModel: DefaultMeta = db.Model
```

but that makes no difference I'm still seeing that mypy error.

Current version of packages is this:

```
mypy                   │ 1.1.1
SQLAlchemy             │ 2.0.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy       │ 3.0.3
```

Does somebody know how write this so mypy is happy? I can always make mypy ignore it, but I somehow want to have this right.

Comment: Same over here. Tired of the ```# type: ignore[assignment]```